# syntax.vim file is missing

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

I jumped on to a colleague's computer and tried opening a C++ file in vim, and got the following error -

```
E484: Can't open file /usr/local/share/vim/syntax/syntax.vim
```

Interestingly, the location `/usr/local/share/vim/` does not even exist. It looks like vim is installed in `/usr/share/vim`

I tried hacking the ~/.vimrc, but I think the ~/.vimrc is fine, because I ssh'ed into another machine, and vim was able to do syntax highlighting there.

This is on debian 7. Also, interestingly, when I did `env` from tcsh, I did not see VIMRUNTIME listed there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: make a symlink from this directory that's vim requesting to VIMRUNTIME directory: `ln -s /usr/local/share/vim path/to/VIMRUNTIME/directory/`

Comment: Make sure you're running the vim that you think you are.  `which vim`.

Answer (score 6):

However,when it comes to me,
I installed vim8.2 through homebrew.
I checked this problem through the internet and
find a post which says

```
brew link vim
```

may help you fix this problem.
(May not be useful when in your case ...)

Comment: this is the neat answer.

Comment: That helped me too with my homebrew installation of vim.

Comment: Thanks bro, it really fix my problem.

Answer (score 3):

My case, did not detect /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syntax.vim
since I updated....

my solution:

## corrects the path

```
ln -s /usr/share/vim/vim81 /usr/share/vim/vim80
```

## corrects the access to colors/

```
ln -s /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/* .vim/colors/
```